# What is the difference between using setTimeout(async function(){}) and setTimeout(function(){})?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

When a request is sent to my server endpoint, I run a function `makeOrder` that is non-blocking.

I wanted to run the function a second time if it failed the first time by using `setTimeout`, but I'm not sure if I should use `async` or not within the `setTimeout` to make sure it doesn't block the event loop.

What I'm doing at the moment is this:

```js
if (await makeOrder(order)) {
    // order was successful
} else {
    // try again in 5 minutes
    setTimeout(async function() {
        makeOrder(order);
    }, 300000);
}
```

Is this correct? (`makeOrder` returns true or false base on if it was successful or not)

I'm wondering if there is a difference in making the code blocking or non-blocking if more requests reach my endpoint if I use async function vs just function?

Comment: I'm assuming by "non-blocking", you mean the call to the function is asynchronous?

Comment: if `makeOder()` is async your code is wrong, because `if (makeOrder())` won't await the result. And as you also don't await the result of `makeOrder` in the timeout's callback, it doesn't make any difference if this callback is `async` or not ...

Comment: @derpirscher sorry that was my mistake of not including the await, I corrected it. My question is just if the code could block the event loop in any way by using setTimeout and if there was any difference between using setTimeout calling an async function or not

Comment: Personally, I would add a `const sleep = ms => new Promise((accept, reject) => setTimeout(accept, ms));` helper, then use `await sleep(300000)` instead of `setTimeout` directly.

Answer (score 1):

The `async` keyword:

- Forces the function to return a promise (which is irrelevant since `setTimeout` ignores the return value).
- Allows you to use the `await` keyword inside the function

It doesn't stop blocking code from being blocking.

Use `async` is you need to manage promises inside the function. There is no other use for it in that context.

The only function you call returns a boolean, not a promise, so you don't have any promises to manage. Adding `async` is pointless (and might confuse you or other people maintaining the code in the future).

Comment: ‘The only function you call returns a boolean, not a promise’ — that was a mistake in the asker’s code.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with recursion. As you can retry with specific duration after your make order was not successful. The failure should be in catch block as it would be intuitive when you want to stop operation after certain retries.

```
function makeOrderWrapper(order, retry) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            if (retry < 0 )
                reject();
            makeOrder(order);
            resolve();
        } catch (exception) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                makeOrderWrapper(url, retry - 1).then(function () {
                    resolve();
                });
            }, 300000);
        }
    });
}

await makeOrderWrapper(order, 3)
```